# Unexpected behaviour after using "deepcopy"

Tags: python, deep-copy

When I run the following code, it doesn't modify the list generated using 'deepcopy', i.e. I get 'mt1' unchanged. If I applied the same code on 'mt', I get the desired result!

```
def subDic(f):
    w = random.randint(2, int(0.7*len(f)))
    s = random.randint(0, len(f)-w)
    idSub = {}
    for i in range(s, s+w):
        idSub[i] = f[i]
    return idSub


ft = [(2,3), (4,8), (1,0), (7,1)]
mt = copy.deepcopy(ft)
random.shuffle(mt)
mt1 = copy.deepcopy(mt)

ftDic = subDic(ft)
for e in mt1:
    if e in ftDic.values():
        mt1.remove(e)
```

Comment: `mt1` is not unchanged, it is a shuffled version of `ft`. Why do you assume that it is unchanged?

Comment: I didn't understand the "problem", the code seems to work as expected.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon the final result should be that the values in the dictionary `ftDic` removed from the list `mt1` so there is no common values!

Comment: @KelvinS I don't understand the problem either, `mt1` remains the same after excuting the code without any values removed from it

Comment: @E.Aly Actually, when I run this code the `mt1` changes, some values are removed (the number of values removed may vary on each execution). For example: `>>> mt1 [(7, 1), (1, 0)]` and `>>> mt1 [(4, 8), (2, 3), (7, 1)]`.

Comment: @KelvinS there should be no common values in `ftDic` and `mt1`, but when I run the code repeatedly, common values appear in some runs... the number of values removed should depend on the number of values in `ftDic` so that `len(ftDic.values()) + len(mt1) == len(ft)`

Comment: @E.Aly maybe the problem is that you are iterating over the `mt1` while removing its values, try something like `[mt1.remove(e) for e in ftDic.values()]` instead of the last 3 lines of code.

Comment: @KelvinS that seemed to be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't iterate over `mt1` while removing its values.

Try something like this:

```
def subDic(f):
    w = random.randint(2, int(0.7*len(f)))
    s = random.randint(0, len(f)-w)
    idSub = {}
    for i in range(s, s+w):
        idSub[i] = f[i]
    return idSub


ft = [(2,3), (4,8), (1,0), (7,1)]
mt = copy.deepcopy(ft)
random.shuffle(mt)
mt1 = copy.deepcopy(mt)

ftDic = subDic(ft)
for e in ftDic.values():
    mt1.remove(e)
```